# Assign value to a list of another class

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I don't know how to add parameters to a list from a subclass. I have this class:

```
public partial class remSolicitudesEnt 
{
    private Solicitud[] solicitudesField;

    public Solicitud[] Solicitudes {
        get {
            return this.solicitudesField;
        }
        set {
            this.solicitudesField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And in my code I have this:

```
private static remSolicitudesEnt getRemSolicitudesEnt()
{
   remSolicitudesEnt filter= new remSolicitudesEnt();

    //WHEN I ADD AN ELEMENT TO A NORMAL LIST...

    List<Profesional> profesionals = new List<Profesional>();

    Profesional p1 = new Profesional();

    profesionals.Add(pd1);

    //BUT HOW CAN I ADD AN ELEMENT TO A LIST FROM THE SUBCLASS??

    Solicitud s = new Solicitud();

    //filter.Solicitudes.Add(s); THIS CAN'T BE DONE

}
```

How Can I add the element "Solicitud" to the list?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class is array not a list. So you have not method Add there. Just change definition of your

class:

```
public partial class remSolicitudesEnt {

    private List<Solicitud> solicitudesField;

    public List<Solicitud> Solicitudes 
    {
        get { return this.solicitudesField; }
        set { this.solicitudesField = value; }
    }
}
```